# What is difference between design from product and design from experience?

Tags: user-centered-design

Would like to know what is difference between design from product and design from experience. Is design from product product-centric? Is design from experience user-centric?

Comment: Should be related to this - UX vs Product Design, what's the difference? (https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/80622/ux-vs-product-design-whats-the-difference) The post is a little old and may be we can have a fresh answer on the original post.

Answer (score 1):

It's all about perspectives, as Product, Design, and Dev aim to deliver what they think is the best product possible: viable (solves for business case), delightful (matches user's expectations), and feasible (can be built in a reasonable time).

[image: perspectives]

Answer (score 0):

Good question, I will try to make it brief:

First of all, they both follow the same process. That's why many people see them as interchangeable.

The main difference is that product designers will work on the product after it has been launched, updating it accordingly.

So the **what** of user experience design and product design is the same but the **when** is different. UX mainly focuses on what happens before the launch and the product designer on what happens after the launch.

Answer (score 0):

### Product Designers:

- Focus on long term strategy
- Help achieve **key** business goals
- Maintain more comprehensive perspective to design
- Make wise **trade-offs**
- Measure KPIs
- Usually, a product designer would ask, “Does this product make sense in the current economy?”

### UX Designers:

- Focus on very specific **user needs**
- Executes **Design thinking process**
- Intended to create a positive user/customer experience
- Usually, a UX designer would ask: “Is this product easy to use?”

Last but not the least, keep in mind that the industry is rapidly changing. Whether you are a UX designer or, Product designer, the industry expects from you that you have a sound knowledge of:

1. How a product aligns with the business model
2. How you should figure out what users need from users mental model
3. How to make feasible designs

> Instead of focusing the differences between UX and product design,
> let's focus on designing product that will create real (effective)
> differences to our nation, society and mankind.